# For which $p>0$ is the series L^2-convergent?

Tags: fourier-analysis

> For which $p>0$ is the series $L^2$-convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^ ∞ \frac{1}{n^p}e^ {ix} $$

Now I've been trying to solve this but just cant get the right answer. Another dude on university told me that the answer should be $p>1/2$ and he was pretty sure of it. He told me they couldnt solve it until they got a Theorem that doesnt exist in the "Fourier Analysis.."-book written by Gerald B.Folland.

[I did a couple of tries like this but didnt come to anything good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mzCY.jpg)
Anyone who think differently and can help me solve this?

Comment: Which $L^2$ space? $L^2([0,2\pi])$? $L^2([0,1])$? …

Comment: Might want to double check that sum - do you mean $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{n^p} e^{inx}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, It doesnt say, but in the previous question (1a), it wanted us to prove that it's $L^2(-pi,pi)$-convergent. This question (1b) doesnt say anything but the text I wrote in this thread. I guess it's $(-pi,pi)$..

Comment: @πr8 Yes, that was a typo! I'm sorry. I just corrected it!

Comment: I think the point was that your summation index is $i$, it should probably be $n$. And the function should probably be $e^{inx}$, not $e^{ix}$ independent of $n$.

Comment: Okay, $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is basically equivalent to $L^2([0,2\pi])$. The point is that the functions are mutually orthogonal in that space.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I switched it! Sorry once again. Im 100% that the function is e^ix

Comment: If the function is independent of $n$, $L^2$ is pretty much a red herring. Then the question is for which $p$ the series $\sum n^{-p}$ converges.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure, but why would the answer be p>1/2 ?

Comment: It wouldn't. It would be $p > 1$ then. The answer is $p > \frac{1}{2}$ for $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}e^{inx},$$ since by the orthogonality you have $$\Biggl\lVert \sum_{n = k}^m \frac{1}{n^p} e^{inx}\Biggr\rVert^2 = \sum_{n = k}^m \frac{1}{n^{2p}} \lVert e^{inx}\rVert^2.$$